# Can not build, run and release android with nativescript

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

After I updated `nativescript` to `version 6.0.2`, I can not run and build android with code `tns run android --bundle` and it shows `JavaScript heap out of memory`
I use typescript for coding and my computer has 16GB of memory, but why is this memory not enough?

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Building project...
Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from P:\..\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
         Applying settings from P:\..\app\App_Resources\Android\settings.json
         + using andorid X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\nativescript-background-http\platforms\android\nativescript_background_http.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\nativescript-camera\platforms\android\nativescript_camera.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\nativescript-facebook\platforms\android\nativescript_facebook.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\nativescript-imagepicker\platforms\android\nativescript_imagepicker.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\nativescript-local-notifications\platforms\android\app-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\nativescript-ui-sidedrawer\platforms\android\TNSSideDrawer-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\nativescript-ui-core\platforms\android\TNSCore-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: P:\..\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar    
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
     1: 00007FF6D8F8C6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeenter code hereHandler+4506
     2: 00007FF6D8F67416 node::MakeCallback+4534
     3: 00007FF6D8F67D90 node_module_register+2032
     4: 00007FF6D928189E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
     5: 00007FF6D92817CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
     6: 00007FF6D9467F94 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
     7: 00007FF6D945EF76 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
     8: 00007FF6D945D5CC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
     9: 00007FF6D9466317 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
    10: 00007FF6D9466396 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
    11: 00007FF6D9590637 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
    12: 00007FF6D960D826 v8::internal::operator<<+73494
    13: 000002DF1B35C5C1

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 134"
```

Comment: Could you try running "env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 tns run android" and see if that works? It basically sets node's V8 heap size to 8192mb.

Answer (score 0):

GC overhead limit exceeded, which can be solved by adding

  `dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }`

to your app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle so it becomes something like this:

```
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    applicationId = "__PACKAGE__"  
    multiDexEnabled true
    generatedDensities = []
  }
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase)

Comment: No, Its full heap like same ploblem

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal window:

**export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096**

then run the **tns run android --device Nexus_5X_API_27** command.